# when one column is null use other column in where db2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have two table i need to intersect the common records.

```
table1
Name epmno date1            date2
ss1   123  01/10/2017     01/10/2017
ss2   124  02/10/2019     01/10/2019
ss3   125  null           01/09/2017
```

table1 condition : select if date1 > 18 months , if date1 was null then use date2 to check > 18 months

```
table2
   epmno date3            
   123  01/10/2017     
   124  02/10/2019    
   125  null
```

table2 condition : select if date3 > 18 months and date3 is null.

to join table1 and table2 I have common field epmno( so i an use where table1.epmno=table2.empno)

query:

```
select empno, name from (select empno,Name from table1  where (date1 is null use date2) > 
current_date - 18 MONTHS) a
(select empno from table2 where date3 > current_date - 18 MONTHS or date3 is null) b where 
a.empno=b.empno;
```

result:

```
Name epmno 
ss1   123
ss3   125
```

how can we write optimal query in this case using db2 syntax , could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

use `coalesce()` function. then `left join` your `table2`

```
select t1.empno, t1.name 
from table1 t1      
left join table2 t2 on t2.empno = t1.empno
where
    coalesce(coalesce(t1.date1, t1.date2), t2.date3) > current_date - 18 MONTHS) a
```

Comment: Hi metal Thanks for the timely help.. is there is a way without using coalesce..

Comment: yes there is, try `case when t1.date1 is null then t1.date2 when t1.date2 is null then t2.date3 else t1.date1 end > current_date - 18 MONTHS`

Comment: table2 condition : select if date3 > 18 months and date3 is null. Need to include these two condition against table2.. could you please check

Comment: `select t1.empno, t1.name 
from table1 t1      
left join table2 t2 on t2.empno = t1.empno
where
    coalesce(t1.date1, t1.date2) > current_date - 18 MONTHS
 or
 (t2.date3 > current_date - 18 MONTHS or t2.date3 is null)`